# Как добавить аргументы в стандартный CONFIGURE_COMMAND в ExternalProject (CMake)?

Tags: cmake

Я добавляю external project в свой cmake проект. По умолчанию flatbuffers собирает примеры и тесты, и если их отключить, то экономится драгоценное время компиляции. Проблема в том, что для того чтобы их отключить мне нужно определить несколько переменных (см. внизу закомметированную строку) и добавить их в `CONFIGURE_COMMAND`. Но, у меня нет переменной `${flatbuffers_SOURCE_DIR}` и заранее задать её не могу (мало ли куда оно будет скачивать).

Как это лучше решить?

`ExternalProject_Add(flatbuffers
  GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/google/flatbuffers.git"
  GIT_TAG "v1.5.0"
  # CONFIGURE_COMMAND cmake ${flatbuffers_SOURCE_DIR} -DFLATBUFFERS_BUILD_TESTS=Off -DFLATBUFFERS_INSTALL=Off -DFLATBUFFERS_BUILD_FLATHASH=Off
  INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
  TEST_COMMAND      ""
)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хотя директория с исходниками, директория сборки и прочие директории для ExternalProject определяются по определенному алгоритму (см. [документацию](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html)), есть простой способ сослаться на эти директории при формировании командной строки для того или иного шага:

- `<SOURCE_DIR>` - директория с исходниками
- `<BINARY_DIR>`  -  директория сборки
- `<INSTALL_DIR>` - директория установки

Пример:

```
CONFIGURE_COMMAND cmake <SOURCE_DIR> -FLATBUFFERS_BUILD_TESTS=Off -DFLATBUFFERS_INSTALL=Off -DFLATBUFFERS_BUILD_FLATHASH=Off
```